# What process is responsible for auto-screen rotation? I want to disable it (on 16.04)

Tags: lenovo, display-rotation

currently I'm trying to disable the process which is responsible for handling the auto-screen rotation on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, which is enabled by default.

So far I did some research on the packages `iio-sensor-proxy` and `inotify-tools`, but I couldn't figure out how to disable it.

Is it possible to just remove `iio-sensor-proxy` to achieve the desired behaviour?

Or would that affect any important process in a negative way and cause anomalies?

Where are the configuration files stored?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This "feature" is pretty damn silly. Why would someone want to have this enabled by default I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 7):

I have since found a more practical way of disabling screen rotation, but it only works in the GNOME desktop environment and not in Unity.

In GNOME click on the top right menu. The button in between the one that opens the Settings menu and that locks your screen controls your screen rotation. Click the button to disable it.

This screenshot was taken from a [similar question for Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/98455/stop-screen-auto-rotate/):

[image: Location of the screen rotation toggle in GNOME]

This feature does not appear to be in Unity. A graphical tool that will at least help you with your screen rotation in Unity is called [ScreenRotator](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/rotate-screen-ubuntu-16-04-indicator-applet).

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 16.10, I was able to disable automatic screen rotation with this train of thought:

1. I confirmed that it was the `iio-sensor-proxy` service that was causing the screen to automatically rotate. Running `systemctl stop iio-sensor-proxy` stops screen rotation until next boot.
2. The `iio-sensor-proxy` service is a `static` SystemD service for some reason and therefore cannot be disabled using `systemctl disable iio-sensor-proxy`, so you have to remove it to disable permanently. However, the scant documentation indicates that this service also controls the ambient light sensor and the compass, which I don't want to disable if I don't have to.
3. Using the `apt-file` utility (which is not installed by default), I determined which files are installed for the package associated with this service, by running `apt-file list iio-sensor-proxy`. It appears to install a configuration file `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-iio-sensor-proxy.rules` - where `udev` is Ubuntu's hardware management subsystem. That seems to be the place to look.
4. Notice that this file contains a line `SUBSYSTEM=="input", ACTION=="add", TAG+="systemd", ENV{ID_INPUT_ACCELEROMETER}=="1", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="iio-sensor-proxy.service"`. This appears to control the accelerometer that triggers the automatic rotation. Comment it out by putting a `#` in front of this line to prevent this service from reading the accelerometer.
5. After a reboot, automatic screen rotation should be disabled while `iio-sensor-proxy` is still running.

Clearly there should be a GUI option for this, let alone a documented way of doing this, but there you go.

Comment: I can't get it to work so that I can try disable it :'(

Comment: @MinaMichael I don't understand - what is you can't get to work?

Comment: automatic screen rotation as a whole. nothing specific just saying

Comment: can confirm that this also works on linux mint! great answer.