# What script is responsible for auto-screen rotation in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, display-rotation

Screen rotation works well, but on my ASUS Transformer Mini, the pen input is rotated incorrectly. I discovered the correct command to rotate it, but I first need to know what script is called to handle screen rotation.

The command to fix the pen input rotation on my laptop is:

```
xinput set-prop "ELAN22A6:00 04F3:22A6 Pen Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
```

The effect only lasts until I rotate the screen (physically) to portrait and back again, and the setting seems to be overwritten, so it's necessary to execute this command every time the screen is rotated back into landscape mode. I have it hotkeyed, but I'd rather fix it in the script that is being run to handle the rotation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: see if the answer here has what you need: https://askubuntu.com/questions/803845/process-responsible-for-auto-screen-rotation-16-04 (16.04 might be different from 18.04/18.10; but I expect it to be a UDEV rule you need to add)

Comment: Nope, not trying to turn it off. I like auto-rotate. It actually works surprisingly well. Just want to be able to fix the input rotation to match the screen rotation.